# Changing styles in paperclip to adjust image size makes the app display' no file chosen' when uploading an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, imagick

In my model pin.rb

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}
```

In pin.html.erb

```
<td><%= image_tag pin.image(:medium) %></td>
```

When I upload an image it gives

> No File Chosen
>   Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

However when I remove "styles..." from pin.rb and '(:medium) from pin.html it works fine.   I want the image size to be adjusted though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you storing the attachment?

Comment: The file is coming from my computer and being stored into Public>>system>>pins>>images

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you forgetting to call url on the attachment?

```
<%= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a couple of years old and was never answered

I'm researching another Paperclip question today, but in this case I would say:

```
<%= image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium) %>
```

as that's the equivalent of what I have in mine.

Don't forget the instance variable in the _form.html.erb as well as the .url method to set the image into the size you want.

For any travelers to this page, as a next step you might want to also look at another post here on how to delete the image in the Edit view.  [Rails file upload (paperclip) on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315198/rails-file-upload-paperclip-on-edit?rq=1)

Cheers