# Rails 4: replace / delete uploaded file in edit view form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, paperclip, attachment

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315198/rails-file-upload-paperclip-on-edit) has already been asked, but the answer is only for Rails 3, so I am taking the liberty of asking a new question.

I have a Rails 4 app, with the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The `Post` model has the following attributes:

```
references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
date :date
time :time
string :subject
string :format
text :copy
attachment :image
```

and the attachment was setup as follows with Paperclip in `Post` model:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" }
validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/png" },
                                :size => { :in => 0..3000.kilobytes }
```

Adding an `image` to a `Post` is working fine, through the following `form`:

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @calendar.posts.build] do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <p>
      <%= f.label :date %><br>
      <%= f.date_select :date %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :time %><br>
      <%= f.time_select :time %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :subject %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :format %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :format %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :copy %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :copy %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :image %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Viewing the `image` attached to a `Post` is also working well, thanks to this `show` view:

```
<h2>Post from <%= @post.date.strftime("%A, %d") %></h2>

<div>
    <p><strong>Date</strong></p>
    <%= @post.date.strftime("%A, %d") %>
</div>
<div>
    <p><strong>Time</strong></p>
    <%= @post.time.strftime("%I:%M %p") %>
</div>
<div>
    <p><strong>Subject</strong></p>
    <%= @post.subject %>
    </div>
<div>
    <p><strong>Format</strong></p>
    <%= @post.format %>
    </div>
<div>
    <p><strong>Copy</strong></p>
    <%= @post.copy %>
</div>
<div>
    <p><strong>Image</strong></p>
    <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:med) %>
</div>
```

However, when I go to the `edit` view, for a post where I have previously uploaded an image, I only see the field that allows me to add an image and a message saying "no file chosen".

The `edit` view uses (for now) the same form as the `new` view, as shown above.

How can I achieve the following:

1. Have the uploaded image appear in the edit page.
2. Allow users to delete this image.
3. Allow users to replace this image with a new one.

–––––

**UPDATE**: I found a way to solve item #1 above, by replacing

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :image %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>
```

with

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <% if @post.image.exists? %>
      <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:med) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

in my `Post` `edit` view.

I am still working on items #2 & #3 and could definitely use some help with these.

–––––

I am happy to share more code if necessary.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #2 - Allow user to delete image, you might find this [SO Issue helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435826/rails-paperclip-how-to-delete-attachment)

OR, as per [Paperclip's documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#deleting-an-attachment) you could simply create a dummy checkbox and, in the update method of your controller, look if the checkbox has been ticked and delete the attachment as mentioned in the documentation.

For #3 - Allow users to replace this image with a new one

Simply rework your code as follow:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <% if @post.image.exists? %>
      <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:med) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</p>
```

This way, the file_field is always present (allowing user to replace or add their image)

Comment: Merci beaucoup Alexandre. For #3, things work like a charm with your code. However, for #2, I am not sure how I should implement this. I will keep digging and update the question if necessary.

Comment: Ca me fait plaisir! I'll edit my answer with an alternate way.

Comment: Parfait. I understand the idea behind creating a checkbox. I would rather have a small "x" button where user click and the image disappear, even if it is not deleted right away (and only deleted when the post is saved). That would require some JS, right?

Comment: You could always create a route that calls a delete_image function in your post_controller and have a link_to that does an ajax call to that route and do some nifty javascript goodness once it's executed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for everything. Bonne journée à Gatineau (I lived in Ottawa for a year).

Comment: Ca me fait plaisir! :)